# How to create an inline link without anchor element

Tags: html, hyperlink

How can I create an inline link to a target without having an anchor element?

I want to reference a specific section in a target page. But because I'm not the owner of that target page, I'm not able to set an anchor element there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browser feature *URL Scroll-To-Text Fragment*.
It's supported by chrome and safari, but unfortunately it's not supported by firefox or old browser versions: https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment

You just have to add `#:~:text=Search` Fragment to your url.

Example:
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink#:~:text=link%20destination

Hints:

- The characters `#:~:` must not be encoded by your web application.
  But beware: Do not disable the url encoding for the full url, if you use user input to build the url. Because the encoding is a security feature to prevent XSS.
- Therefore I don't provide a real link in my answer, because this link is not working here, as `~` is encoded by stackoverflow. So just copy and paste the link to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of this answers your question. I've created an inline element that  scrolls the page to a specific element without the anchor tag. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```js
/* JAVASCRIPT */

function goTo() {      
  const targetElement = document.querySelector('#target')
  window.scroll(0, targetElement)
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

span { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<span onclick="goTo()">Link</span>
```

Comment: I just fixed 2 issues, when running the code.
It won't work for external references (e.g. wikipedia). But my question was not that specific and nevertheless it's an interesting solution.

Comment: Let me know how you're handling it. Happy to help.

Comment: I prefer the Scroll-To-Text Fragment solution. But I think this solution is also a good one.